# Best way to removing Qty box near to Add to Cart button in magento product detail page

Tags: magento

I can edit the phtml file `base->default->template->catalog->product->view->addtocart.phtml`
and remove the button.
Is there, any other method like overriding the template using custom module or using local.xml file.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest only hiding it.
magento does require quantity to be supplied when yo add to cart, so a missing input would be an issue, you would have to replace it with a hidden input field.

So, as i started, just use CSS to set Display:none; on the field.